# Pivot4J not showing int Pentaho Business Analytics - Community Edition

Tags: pentaho-cde

I am taking a course on Coursera and we have been asked to use the community version of Pentaho Business Analytics (PBA).

I have download the latest PBA server and plugin for Pivot4J, however, when I launch the web interface and click on new, I do not see the Create Pivot4J View as shown in most demos.

I have launched the interface on 2 systems with Windows 8.1 Pro and Windows 10 Pro OS running on them.

Can someone help me out please as the deadline for me to turn in my work is in 3 days?

Thank you.

Please see screenshot below of what I have tried to explain above.

[http://localhost:8080 Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uozjD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with 0.9 version from pivot4j site and maybe Pentaho 6 version is note yet supported so try 5.4 ba server.

Comment: Thanks @Fenix for suggesting a change in versions. I had downloaded the Pentaho 6.0 Release for Business Analytics application and the Pentaho BI Plugin - Stable Release (pivot4j-pentaho-0.9-plugin.zip) but it did not work as required (couldn't see the Create New Pivot4J View option).


After I downloaded the Development Snapshot of the Pentaho BI Plugin (pivot4j-pentaho-1.0-SNAPSHOT-plugin.zip), it worked well and I was able to see the Create New Pivot4J View option.

Answer (score 1):

You should download and unzip Pivot4J plugin into:  ./pentaho-solutions/system folder in the BIserver, follow:
[this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140809062754/http://blog.professorcoruja.com:80/2013/02/pivot4j-pentaho-bi-plugin.html)
or if this still does not show the pivot4j option you can install it through the Marketplace, there you can install/unistall pluggins, including pivot4j.

[image: select Marketplace option]

After you install or update stop and start the server and it will work.
[image: install pivot4j]

Answer (score 0):

When you unzip the file `pivot4j-pentaho-0.9-plugin.zip` it will create a folder called `pivot4j`. Don't move the contents in the folder move the entire folder to:

```
C:\program files\pentaho\biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\system\pivot4j\
```

This is will work if you are not seeing the plugin in the drop down in `Pentaho`.

Granted everything else was done correctly.

Comment: I tried this in Ubuntu with Pentaho 6 and doesn't works